# How to add jquery events to added classes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, image-gallery

I am trying to create an image gallery, I am using numbers instead of left/right arrows. At the moment, I am trying to get it working with only 2 image (i.g 2 numbers)

this is the html . the id page, is the highlighted number

```
 <div class="grid_1 pagelink" id="page"><p><a href="">1</a></p></div> 
<div class="grid_1 pagelink"><p><a href="">2</a></p></div>
```

the first time the page loads, the code below works. so when I click on link 2 the the code bellow runs fine. But then I want the same code to be triggered when I click back on the first link; but when I do that, the page refreshes by ignoring the code bellow:

```
 $('.pagelink').live('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
        var frame = $(this).text() - 1;
        var frames =     240 * frame;
    //  $('#gal').animate({marginLeft:'500px'},'slow'); 
        $('#gal').animate({marginLeft:  "+="+frames+'px'},'slow');
    $(this).attr('id', 'page').removeClass('pagelink');
    $('#page').addClass('pagelink').removeAttr('id','page');
       // $('#book').animate({    left: '50'  });
    })
```

I thought that the .live() would do that for me but it is not working.

I hope you could help

thank you

Comment: I am trying to do similar, and running into similar problem. The event is already binded when you first click the links to load gallery, so when i go back to the gallery, it wants to fire new event binding and fails to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Previous, this is because you are removing the class of link "pagelink" which were used to map the clicked event.

Also, use another class instead of id(#page) to identify the #page link, id might be problem if its already assign to other link. like

```
$(this).removeClass('pagelink').addClass('page');
$('.page').addClass('pagelink').removeClass('page');
```

Comment: I thought that at first aswell. But it turns out after the click event handler is set, changing the class doesn't matter.  example: http://jsfiddle.net/WDWqT/3/

Comment: just realized the problem see answer again

Comment: @mazz: yes with a normal click this is the case, but live works differently and in that case, removing the class will break the event handler: http://jsfiddle.net/8gLkC/

Comment: Oh, oops, didn't see the .live

Comment: @Naren: I think you had the right answer before. Want to put it back so we can vote for it?

Comment: I just edited answer and also suggested other way to avoid id.

Comment: the first line refferes to link 2 (so I add class page)
2nd line referes to link one (which had the class page hard coded, so I am removing it)
I think I am right there

Comment: yes, but you have added id to current link in first line and in next line you have finding with that id and this time there are two links with id=page so that creates problem. you can try to change the sequence of these line, that probably work

Answer (score 1):

live should work fine. i think you have a bug in your code, and its probably here:

```
$(this).attr('id', 'page').removeClass('pagelink');
$('#page').addClass('pagelink').removeAttr('id','page');
```

what exactly are you trying to accomplish with this code?

when you click on page2, the you set the div's id to be `page`, but now you have 2 elements with an id of page, and when you select that id, you get the first one (ie page1), but you still remove the class `pagelink` from page2

in other words, **the bug is that at some point you will have 2 elements with the same id** (and ids must be unique btw) so when you select that id with `$('#page')` you always get the first one

Comment: is it that on the first line I am adding the id#page to the 2nd link and removing pagelink, then on the first link I am adding #pagelink and removing page - the #page {is the highlighted div} and the #linkpage{is the normal div} - on pageload the first link is highlighted - then when I highlight the 2nd link, I can't the get the first link to highlight on click

Comment: the id #page = visited state the class pagelink = normal state
so link2 before I click it - it is normal, after I click it, it is visited (#page)- at the same time I need to remove id#page from link1.

Now link2 is visited(#page) and link1 is normal(#pagelink) - THIS IS WHERE MY CODE STOPS as when I try to make link one visited it does not work